# Import Full DB to MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoimport, mongorestore

I am trying to execute the following command
mongorestore -d MyDBTEST /users/myusername/documents/supportdbdump

inside the supportdbdump there is a lot of subdirectory with JSON files in them.
the error I am getting is
"don't know what to do with subdirectory "supportdbdump/XXX", skipping
"don't know what to do with subdirectory "supportdbdump/XXX2", skipping
"don't know what to do with subdirectory "supportdbdump/XXX3", skipping
and etc...

what is the problem here?

Comment: maybe your backup is in subdirectory

Answer (score 0):

I have a mongodb in localhost which have three db called `db1`、`db2`、`db3`

I execute below command at D:\

1. `mongodump`

D:\dump\db1

D:\dump\db2

D:\dump\db3

2. `mongorestore -d MyDBTEST D:\dump\db1`

My localhost would now have `db1`、`db2`、`db3`、`MyDBTEST`